# Inputting integers in to an array Error?

Tags: java, arrays, input

The purpose of my code is to display the student number and their respective grade as follows:

```
             Student               Grade
                1                   53
                2                   45
```

So on...

I used a 5x2 array, in which the user can input the values for the grade...

However I run in to a problem, when inputting the grades, for some reason I have to input 3 values, out of all the 3 inputted values only the 3rd is considered.

My problems:

(1) Why is it that I am even able to enter 3 values per student (Should only be able to input 1 value per student).

(2) Why is it the 3rd value that is being considered?

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class practice {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] studentGrade = new int[5][2];

        for(int i = 0; i<5; i++) {
            studentGrade[i][0] = i+1;
        }

        for(int j = 0; j<5; j++) {
            System.out.printf("Student %s: ", j+1);
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            if(input.nextInt()>=0 && input.nextInt()<=100) {
                studentGrade[j][1] = input.nextInt();
            }
            else {
                studentGrade[j][1] = 0;
                System.out.printf("Student %s's mark has been defaulted", j);
            }
        }

        System.out.print("\nStudent \t Grade");
        for(int s=0; s<5; s++) {
            System.out.print("\n" + studentGrade[s][0] +"\t" + "\t " + studentGrade[s][1]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`input.nextInt()` *consumes* the next integer in the stream.

You need to do this:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
    System.out.printf("Student %s: ", j+1);
    int num = input.nextInt();
    if (num >= 0 && num <= 100)
        studentGrade[j][1] = num;
    else {
        studentGrade[j][1] = 0;
        System.out.printf("Student %s's mark has been defaulted", j+1);
    }
}
```

This will make it so that you read the number being input only once, and then you use that number when checking boundaries and then setting the grade.

Comment: @RamanSB Also note that for the "student's mark has been defaulted" `printf` you probably also want to use `j+1` instead of `j`. I noticed that and fixed it, but I wanted to make sure you see it, and it didn't warrant enough attention in the actual answer :D